# postgresql CREATE ROLE doesn't add a user

Tags: postgresql

I am very new to Postgresql. I am using docker image of Postgresql.
I am creating a user with `CREATE USER` or `CREATE ROLE`, the role get created yet I can't login and the new user is not added to pg_user, yet another postgres user shows up in pg_user.

```
postgres@af69c869e149:/home$ psql -U postgres
psql (12.10 (Ubuntu 12.10-1.pgdg20.04+1+b1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}

postgres=# SELECT user, valuntil FROM pg_user;
   user   | valuntil 
----------+----------
 postgres | 
(1 row)

postgres=# CREATE ROLE testrole WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'secretphrase' CREATEDB;
CREATE ROLE
postgres=# \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
 testrole  | Create DB                                                  | {}

postgres=# SELECT user, valuntil FROM pg_user;
   user   | valuntil 
----------+----------
 postgres | 
 postgres | 
(2 rows)

postgres=# \q
postgres@2f085f2da890:/home$ psql -U testrole
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "testrole"
```

I tried this work on Postgresql-12 and Postgresql-14 with the same fault.
What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit 05/11/22:**
Thank you @Adrian Klaver!
here is mu pg_hba.conf

```
# local         DATABASE  USER  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
host all all all scram-sha-256

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
```

I have `host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256` in the pg_hba.conf file.

I only created a role, I didn’t create a database one by the role.
Apparently I need to create a database with the same name of the role to be able to log in. Is this right?
Here is how I got to this conclusion

```
postgres@b14b022f2606:/home$ psql -U postgres
psql (12.10 (Ubuntu 12.10-1.pgdg20.04+1+b1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# CREATE ROLE testrole WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'secretphrase' CREATEDB;
CREATE ROLE
postgres=# \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
 testrole  | Create DB                                                  | {}

postgres=# psql -U testrole -h 127.0.0.1
postgres-# exit
Use \q to quit.
postgres-# \q
postgres@b14b022f2606:/home$ psql -U testrole -h 127.0.0.1
Password for user testrole: 
psql: error: connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "testrole"
connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "testrole"
postgres@b14b022f2606:/home$ psql -U testrole -h 127.0.0.1
Password for user testrole: 
psql: error: connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: FATAL:  database "testrole" does not exist
```

Then I tried

```
postgres@a4cfc3594dd5:/home$ psql
psql (12.10 (Ubuntu 12.10-1.pgdg20.04+1+b1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}

postgres=# CREATE DATABASE testdb OWNER testdb;
ERROR:  role "testdb" does not exist
postgres=# CREATE ROLE testdb WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'secretphrase' CREATEDB;
CREATE ROLE
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE testdb OWNER testdb;
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=# \q
postgres@a4cfc3594dd5:/home$ psql -U testdb -h 127.0.0.1
Password for user testdb: 
psql (12.10 (Ubuntu 12.10-1.pgdg20.04+1+b1))
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.3, cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

testdb=>
```

Which is successful.

-Thanks

Comment: Not reading the error message, `...connection to server on socket...` and `Peer authentication failed for user "testrole`. And not reading the docs, [Client authentication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html). Best guess is your `pg_hba.conf` has `peer` authentication set up for `local(socket)` connections. Either change that to password authentication  or see if  there is `host` line that has password(md5 or scram-256) set up and do: `psql -U testrole -h localhost`. Assuming there is `host` line for `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Thanks Adrian! I added an Edit section to show `pg_hba.conf` contents and a conclusion.

Comment: Did you reload/restart the server to catch the `pg_hba.conf` changes? No roles are global to all the databases in a Postgres cluster.

Comment: Thank you Adrian! I think I found my misunderstanding.

Comment: I should login to a DB with a user, I can't login to a user that is not attached to any DB. Incase the user and the DB have the same name, I can only use the user name to login, yet it is actually logging in to the DB. Is my understanding right?

Answer (score 0):

`user` is not a column of `pg_user`, but a function that returns the current user, so it is no wonder that you get the same result for both rows. It is annoying, but the SQL standard in its unfathomable wisdom decreed that there be some functions *without* parentheses, which is very effective in confusing users.